# AWS SAM build failing for Lambda Java8 when including dependent maven modules

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-toolkit

I am implementing a simple lambda handler in Java8. Since many more lambdas are going to be implemented in the future and they all need to be packaged as jars I have structured the maven project with one maven module for each lambda.
All works well if the lambda only includes dependencies on maven-repo libraries.

However the lambda modules have common code, and when i try to extract that as an extra module and add the dependencies of that like so in the lambda module pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.neo.step</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Sam build fails with no specific message.

Comment: Did you reimport the maven project or is auto import active?
Did you run `mvn install`? 
Could you post the parent `pom.xml`.
BTW: I suggest to use [mavens dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to organize the dependencies and versions.

Comment: @Peter Thnx, it was the local repo install that needed to run first :) You can add your response if you want.